# Python - Import python file in the same dir actually imports the class inside that file with the same name instead of the file

Tags: python, import, path

First question here and have been doing lengthy research before asking this question but can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying to import a file in the same directory through a standard import statement:

```
import foo
```

files look like this:

```
project_folder
---->foo
---->etc.
```

It does not work even though the working directory seems to be in order. The error I get is that foo is trying to import a selfmade module which again imports another file inside that module. So the following happens:

```
file = wip_file.py
>import foo
------------
file = foo.py
>from spam import eggs, bacon
------------
file = eggs.py
>import bacon
```

Where spam is a self-created module in site-packages. Now the error I receive is that there is no module named bacon while importing it in the eggs.py. And the funny thing is that bacon is imported succesfully in foo.py.

Then I tried to import it through the folder name above it:

```
from project_folder import foo
```

however by doing it this way it imported the class inside the file foo which was called foo as well. The same script ran fine on another PC. So I guess something is messed up with my paths in PyCharm. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this, reset standards or any other thing I could try?

So much thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your module have an empty \__init__.py file? That's how python knows it's a module you're trying to import. Also, what version of python are you using?

Comment: Is module `foo` not named `foo.py`? That'll cause problems.

Comment: In the self created module there is an init file indeed. I am using Python 3.6, the other PC 3.4. However so far we have not had any issues with this.. The foo.py file is not a module.

Comment: yes foo is a foo.py. I just want to import a method from that file.

Comment: *"It does not seem to work"*: In what way doesn't it work? How do you know it doesn't work? Be explicit and edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. One way or another the import was done wrong in eggs.py. Should have been:

```
from . import bacon
```

Now it works all fine.

Thanks for the quick responses!